# does array_unique start new array index numbers?

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array that uses integers as indexes. (1, 2, 3, etc). When I use the array_unique function on it, will the new array values be stored with new indexes starting from 1? Or does this new array use the same indexes from the previous array?

Thanks, any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does use the same indexes .. as [`array_unique()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) preserve keys..

From the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)..

> **Note that keys are preserved.** array_unique() sorts the values treated
>   as string at first, then will keep the first key encountered for every
>   value, and ignore all following keys. It does not mean that the key of
>   the first related value from the unsorted array will be kept.

---

> Nope. I want to put them into a new array starting from index 1. Any
>   way to do that then?

Array indices start with **0** as the default index ! The below code creates a new array with index starting from 1.

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,3);
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    $new_arr[++$k]=$v;
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
```

Comment: Okay, so is there anyway I can copy these into a new array starting from index 1? Because it would be a huge pain for me to find the original's index numbers for the duplicates.

Comment: You don't want the keys to be preserved ? Maybe you can use .. `$newarr = array_values(array_unique($youroldarray));`

Comment: Nope. I want to put them into a new array starting from index 1. Any way to do that then?

Comment: so will that put them into a new array starting from index 1?